# Finite symmetric difference equivalence relation on A $\subseteq \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations

Given the equivalence relation:
$A \sim B $ $\iff$ $A \Delta B$ is finite, where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference,
we define: $S := \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \mid A \sim \mathbb{N} \}$.
I am asked to calculate $\left| S \right|$.

Any tips, or suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Sets in what you have labeled as $S$ here are known by a specific name... "*Co-finite*" sets.  That is, they are the sets such that $\Bbb N\setminus A$ is finite.  Make sure you can understand why these definitions match.

Comment: With regards to the size of $S$... in the same way we can list finite sets: $\{\},\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\},\{2\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\},\{3\},\{0,3\},\{1,3\},\dots$  we can go about listing the co-finite sets in the same way... $\Bbb N\setminus \{\}, \Bbb N\setminus\{0\},\Bbb N\setminus \{1\},\dots$

Comment: I understand why the definitions match (because of how we define symmetric difference: $(A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ ). What I'm still missing is the map, or rather how to define the set B such that $\mathbb{N} \setminus B$ is finite. I have a mental picture of taking $\mathbb{N}$ from the "end" and stopping each time leaving just a singleton, then a set containing 2 elements etc. but I'm not sure how to construct the proof of the lower bound.

Comment: $\mathbb N\setminus A$ is finite iff $\{k\geqslant N\} \subseteq A$ for sufficiently large $N$, meaning there can't be infinitely many "holes" in $\mathbb N$